# ossrh nexus staging - what determines the repository id?

Tags: maven, nexus

I am deploying my project to maven central and I notice that I have no control on the repository id, which seems to be automatically generated and in my case, seems to be incorrect and hence the deployment fails. I could have done something wrong but I do now know where to look. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

My pom:

```
<groupId>uk.ac.shef.dcs</groupId>
<artifactId>sti</artifactId>
<version>1.0alpha</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-source-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-javadoc-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-gpg-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sign</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.7</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                    <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                    <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

When running 'mvn clean deploy', it generates log like this:

```
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org:443/service/local/staging/deployByRepositoryId/ukacshefdcsjate-1015/uk/ac/shef/dcs
```

I do not know how it generates this id: ukacshefdcsjate-1015. I thought it should corresponds to the project package path, but my package should be uk.ac.shef.dcs.sti. and I never had a package called 'jate' in my project. In fact, jate is another project I already released to maven central.

And I think it is this problem that after running 'mvn clean deploy', I could not see anything available from: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/

Comment: How does the deployment fail?

Comment: After deployment, if you visit https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/uk/ac/shef/dcs/ there is no 'sti' folder which I expect to contain the uploaded artifacts